# Spring data jpa SPEL dynamically adds where JPQL clause

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

query parameter object

```kotlin
data class GetSourceListRequest(
    val category: List<Int>,
    val text: String,
    val tag: List<Int>,
    val order: Sort.Direction,  
    val pageSize: Int,    
    val currentPage: Int
)
```

query repository

```kotlin
interface ISourceItemDao : JpaRepository<SourceItemEntity, Long>, CrudRepository<SourceItemEntity, Long> {
  @Query(
        """
        select e.id 
        from SourceItemEntity e
        left join SourceItemToCategoryEntity ic on e.id = ic.itemId
        #{request.category.size() > 0 ? 'where ic.categoryId in (:#{#request.category}' : 'q')}
        where ic.categoryId in (:#{#request.category})
        """
    )
    fun getIdByCondition(request: GetSourceListRequest, pageable: Pageable): Page<Long>
}
```

The key code is this line (The code here is wrong):

```
#{request.category.size() > 0 ? 'where ic.categoryId in (:#{#request.category})' : ''}
```

I hope that when `#{request.category}` is an empty list, the `where` clause is not added, and when it is not an empty list, the `where` clause is added.

I just learned `Spring Data JPA`, and I didn't find out how to write such a spel statement.

dependencies:

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.4</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

## Result

After help finally my code is as follows:

```kotlin
@Query(
        """
        select e.id 
        from SourceItemEntity e
        left join SourceItemToCategoryEntity ic on e.id = ic.itemId
        where (:#{#request.category.isEmpty()} = true)
        or (:#{#request.category.isEmpty()} = false and ic.categoryId in (:#{#request.category})) 
        """
    )
    fun getIdByCondition(request: GetSourceListRequest, pageable: Pageable): Page<Long>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in your code you don't need to extend from `CrudRepository` having the interface extending `JpaRepository`.

<s>Also I see that you have duplicated `where` clause so, I suggest to leave only one of it simplified with `Collection.isEmpty()` method:</s>

All right, it turned out that you cannot use `?` expression of SpEL mixed with JPQL syntax as query validation fails in this case. For you method you can dodge this limitation as:

```
interface ISourceItemDao : JpaRepository<SourceItemEntity, Long> {
  @Query(
        """
        select e.id 
        from SourceItemEntity e
        left join SourceItemToCategoryEntity ic on e.id = ic.itemId
        where (:#{#request.category.isEmpty()} = true)
           or (:#{#request.category.isEmpty()} = false and ic.categoryId in :request.category)
        """
    )
    fun getIdByCondition(request: GetSourceListRequest, pageable: Pageable): Page<Long>
}
```

I've checked this on my own project having `Child` and `Parent` entities and this query works for me:

```java
@Query("select child from Child child " +
  " join child.parent parent " +
  " where (:#{#ids.isEmpty()} = true) " +
  "    or (:#{#ids.isEmpty()} = false and parent.id in :ids)")
List<Child> findAllByParentIds1(@Param("ids") Collection<Long> ids);
```

If your query fails then try to extract the collection and use it directly:

```
interface ISourceItemDao : JpaRepository<SourceItemEntity, Long> {
  @Query(
        """
        select e.id 
        from SourceItemEntity e
        left join SourceItemToCategoryEntity ic on e.id = ic.itemId
        where (:#{#category.isEmpty()} = true)
           or (:#{#category.isEmpty()} = false and ic.categoryId in :category)
        """
    )
    fun getIdByCondition(category: Collection<Long>, pageable: Pageable): Page<Long>
}
```

Comment: The code does not run correctly, prompting `JDBC style parameters (?) are not supported for JPA queries`

Comment: Sometimes even the compilation fails, prompting `',', <expression>, <join>, <operator>, FETCH, GROUP, HAVING, LIMIT, OFFSET, ORDER, WHERE or WITH expected, got '#{request.category. ..'`. my best guess, `#{}` cannot contain the keyword `where`

Comment: @SageJustus apparently, you cannot use `?` as part of SPeL expression along with JPQL query syntax. See updated query.